# Accesing Samba share from Windows

Tags: centos, samba

I have a CentOS machine with samba installed and configured like so:

```
 [global]
 security = user
 workgroup = mycompany
```

and one share

```
 [myshare]
 path = /srv/mysrvapp
 writable = yes
 valid user = centos
 public = no
```

The folder /srv/mysrvapp has owner set to *centos* and full rights on it (chmod 777). From Linux, conected with *centos* user, everything works ok. 
*centos* user is also added to samba user database with a password. The samba service is restarted.

When I try to map this share from windows (\CentMachine\myshare), I can connect to the share using *centos* and it's samba password, but I can only see the folders in the share, I cannot see the files created under linux and I cannot create files or folders from windows. I checked in Linux and files and folders have the same rights (including writing and settting centos as owner)

The Win machine is part of domain "mycompany", but the linux machine is not part of domain.

Any suggestions why I can't write to this share or why the files are not shown? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it ... I needed to disable SELinux